# How to concurrently modify different elements of an array contained in Arc using Rust multithreading?

Tags: arrays, multithreading, rust, concurrency

Different rows in the array arr come from different row vectors. I want to try to use Rust multi-threading to write different rows of arr to speed up the construction of arr. Below is the code I tested:

[link to rustplaground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2024&gist=3510ca7122f888ee2c2281a1511d79b1)

```
#![allow(dead_code)]
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Instant;

fn main() {
    let mut arr = Arc::new([[0; 2]; 2]);
    let arr1 = Arc::clone(&mut arr);

    let t1 = Instant::now();  //timing starting point

    let mut handles = Vec::new();
    for i in 1..=2 {
        let mut arr = Arc::clone(&mut arr);
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut c1 = Arc::clone(&mut arr);
            let ptr = Arc::get_mut(&mut c1).unwrap();
            //Modify the contents of each line in arr in different threads            
            ptr[i] = [10, 100]; 
        });
        handles.push(handle);
    }
    for h in handles {
        h.join().unwrap();
    }

    let tot1 = t1.elapsed();  //timing end

    println!("arr = {:?}", arr1);
    println!("time consumed: {:?}", tot1);
}
```

However, the compile result in rust-playground is:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 5.97s
     Running `target/debug/playground`
thread 'thread '<unnamed>' panicked at src/main.rs:19:45:
called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
<unnamed>' panicked at src/main.rs:19:45:
called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value
thread 'main' panicked at src/main.rs:25:18:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Any { .. }
```

Please tell me how to modify my code, or is there any other solution to achieve the requirements?

Comment: You need interior mutability as explained in the linked question.

Comment: And you might want to read the documentation for `Arc::get_mut`, it can only succeed if the rc it's invoked on is the only reference to the memory location, but here you have at least 3 refs to the array during any given thread execution: the original array, the per-iteration clone, and the completely unnecessary clone you create inside the thread.

Comment: Also interior mutability is not necessarily necessary here, you can also use iterators and scoped threads to make the compiler understands that your borrows while concurrent (and even parallel) are non-overlapping. Although for fairly obvious reasons this is inefficient as all hell, even rayon's `par_iter_mut` might not be efficient enough to beat a serial iteration with how little work is being done. But if the real creation is a lot more expensive it might work out.